# Add methods dynamically inside a class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to add setters & getters for items that will be put in session storage. I am writing these methods inside a service. But I am getting transpile error when I try to invoke these functions in my component.

Here is the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilitiesService {
    public keySet = [
        "CalendarDates", 
        "LastPublishedSchedule", 
        "ManageStores",
        "SelectedStore"
    ];

    constructor() {
        this.addGetSetClearFunctions();
    }

    addGetFunction(key: string) {
        UtilitiesService["get" + key] = function() {
            return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
        }
    }

    addSetFunction(key: string) {
        UtilitiesService["set" + key] = function(value) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        }
    }

    addClearFunction(key: string) {
        UtilitiesService["clear" + key] = function() {
            sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    }

    clearAll() {
        sessionStorage.clear();
    }

    addGetSetClearFunctions() {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.keySet.length; i++) {
            this.addGetFunction(this.keySet[i]);
            this.addSetFunction(this.keySet[i]);
            this.addClearFunction(this.keySet[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to call inside a set method inside a component:

```
this.utilService.setLastPublishedSchedule(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Note: *utilService* is injected correctly and other auxiliary functions of it(which I didn't put here are executing successfully).

Edit # 1: This is the error I am getting:

> ERROR in
>   src/app/dashboard/components/schedule/schedule.component.ts(344,22):
>   error TS2339: Property 'setLastPublishedSchedule' does not exist on
>   type 'UtilitiesService'.

Edit # 2:
I tried calling the method by:

```
this.utilService['setLastPublishedSchedule'](argument here)
```

I got this run-time error:

> ERROR TypeError: _this.utilService.setLastPublishedSchedule is not a
>   function

Comment: What is the transpile error you are getting?

Comment: ERROR in src/app/dashboard/components/schedule/schedule.component.ts(344,22): error TS2339: Property 'setLastPublishedSchedule' does not exist on type 'UtilitiesService'.

Comment: you could call it this way: `this.utilService['setLastPublishedSchedule'](argument here);` or you could cast it to `any` before calling it. The transpile error is for typesafety which is a big reason why typescript exists.

Comment: A better solution would be to add a method that takes a string and returns some key. That would not break typesafty

Comment: TypeScript is statically typed. You are trying to statically use a dynamic property on a class.

Comment: I tried with this.utilService['setLastPublishedSchedule'](argument here). I am getting a runtime error. Please check for edit #2.

Comment: Based on the code you are creating static methods which is why the method fails in your 2nd attempt. It might work if you added it to the prototype of `this` but I would prefer a solution like the one you accepted below. Hope it all makes sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates the method does not exist. There are ways around this (like casting to `any`) but they break typesafety. A better solution is to add a method that takes a key as parameter to your service and call it that way.

```
setValue(key: "CalendarDates"|"LastPublishedSchedule"|"ManageStores"|"SelectedStore", value: string) {
   sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

```
this.utilService.setValue("LastPublishedSchedule", JSON.stringify(response));
```

You can repeat this pattern for other methods like retrieval of the value or clearing of the value.

*Also you do not have to constrain the key to a list of values but because I noticed you did have a constraint on what keys you were using I added it to the key argument parameter.*

Comment: I did add setters & getters in my previous project using angularjs in the same way I asked in my question. But I understand that it's not better to do it in typescript. Changing my code according to this answer. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Kaushik - glad to help!